# How to display different delivery messages depending on tag and available stock in shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I hope someone can help me with this. Im trying to display a delivery status on certain tagged items that are set to oversell.

first im looking if the product is tagged with 'perfume' and then if stock inventory is above or below 0

i have pieced this code together from a few examples on stack (im very new to this)

```
{% if product.tags contains 'perfume' and current_variant.inventory_quantity <=0 %}
  <div>No inventory, customer allowed to order but has long wait' = Out of Stock please allow 20-30 days for delivery</div>
 
{% elsif product.tags contains 'perfume' and current_variant.inventory_quantity <=1 %}
  <div>No inventory, but customer allowed to order' = Order now for delivery within 7 days</div>
 
{% else %}
  <div>Items in stock' = We have {{ current_variant.inventory_quantity }} in stock for delivery in 4-6 days.</div>
 
{% endif %}
```

when i refresh product all i get is the else output which shows a negative stock count, i have tried different tags and also tried...

```
{% if collection.handle== 'perfume' %}
```

---

THANKS KOOSA

---

Here is the edited version of your code

It shows me the output for both rules on my product page

```
        <div class="productShippingInformation">
          
          {% if product.tags contains 'Discount Enabled' and current_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %}
          
         {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1 %}
           Delivered in 4-6 days.
         {% endif %}
         {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
          <b>Delivered in 10-14 days.</b>
             {% endif %}
          
               

          {% if product.tags contains 'Perfume & Aftershave' and current_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %}

    {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
      <div><b>Delivery in 2021.</b> please allow 20-30 days for delivery</div>
 
    {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1 %}
      <div>Order now for delivery within 7 days</div>

    {% endif %}

{% else %}
  <div>in stock for delivery in 4-6 days.</div>

{% endif %}
```

---

### I think this is the answer
thanks for the help :)

```
        <div class="productShippingInformation">
          
          {% if product.tags contains 'Discount Enabled' and current_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %}
          
         {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1 %}
           Delivered in 4-6 days.
         {% endif %}
         {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and product.tags contains 'Discount Enabled'%}
          <b>Delivered in 10-14 days.</b>
             {% endif %}
          </div>
        <div class="productShippingInformation">       

          {% if product.tags contains 'Perfume & Aftershave' and current_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %}

    {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
      <div><b>Delivery in 2021.</b> please allow 20-30 days for delivery</div>
 
    {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1 %}
      <div>Order now for delivery within 7 days</div>

    {% endif %}



{% endif %}
        
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this like so:

```
{% if product.tags contains 'perfume' and current_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %}

    {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
      <div>Out of Stock please allow 20-30 days for delivery</div>
 
    {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1 %}
      <div>Order now for delivery within 7 days</div>

    {% endif %}

{% else %}
  <div>We have {{ current_variant.inventory_quantity }} in stock for delivery in 4-6 days.</div>

{% endif %}
```

It looks like your main problem was `current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 1` when it should have been `current_variant.inventory_quantity >= 1`

Comment: Brilliant - Thankyou!


i do have a slight problem, when im running this rule i want two types of messaging depending on the tag, so i have doubled it up and the rule seems to show on all products...

Comment: .i have added the code into my original question as it wont allow me to put in comments

Comment: @Anthony - no problems, remember to mark this answer as correct!